# Cmake Project to Catkin

Tags: catkin, root, linking, library, libraries

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey every one,
I have the following folder structure of a pure cmake project:

```
 projectfolder/
 -  code/
          ...
 -  build/
          ...
 -  cmake/
          CompilerOptions.cmake 
          ...
 -  other/
          ...
```

which can be compiled by the following commands without problem:

```
$ cd build 
$ cmake ..
$ make
```

I would like to catkinize this package without interfering with its complex dependency structure.
Basically build the package normally from the same root "/build"
and than link the created libraries to the catkin libraries.
Unfortunately when I use catkin_make the root of the cmake is changing.
This can be seen as I get an cmake error for not finding CompilerOptions.cmake (which is in build).
I tried to `Set(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/projectfolder)`, but without the desired behavior.
How can I change the catkin_make path accordingly, if I have the structure:

```
catkinws/
-    build
-    devel
-    src/
             projectfolder/
             -  code/
                            ...
             -  build/
                            ...
             -  cmake/
                           CompilerOptions.cmake 
                           ...
             -  other/
                           ...
```

Thank you very much for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217683/cmake-project-to-catkin/) by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2015-09-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at CMake's `add_subdirectory` command: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_subdirectory.html ; it should allow you to write a top-level CMakeLists that invokes the existing cmake files.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1